# How to use condition variables?

Tags: ruby, mutex, deadlock, race-condition, producer-consumer

There aren't many resources on Condition Variables in Ruby, however most of them are wrong. Like [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html#UF), [tutorial here](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_threads.html#conditionvariables) or [post here](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/ruby-condition-variables/) - all of them suffer with possible deadlock.

We could solve the problem by starting threads in given order and maybe putting some `sleep` in between to enforce synchronization. But that's just postponing the real problem.

I rewrote the code into a classical [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem):

```
require 'thread'
queue = []
mutex = Mutex.new
resource = ConditionVariable.new
threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do 
      resource.wait(mutex)
      value = queue.pop
      print "consumed #{value}\n"
    end
  end
end

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do
      queue << i
      print "#{i} produced\n"
      resource.signal
    end
    sleep(1) #simulate expense
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Sometimes you will get this (but not always):

```
0 produced
1 produced
consumed 0
2 produced
consumed 1
3 produced
consumed 2
4 produced
consumed 3
producer-consumer.rb:30:in `join': deadlock detected (fatal)
        from producer-consumer.rb:30:in `each'
        from producer-consumer.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

What is the correct solution?

Comment: What is a problem you are trying to solve with condition variables? Producer-consumer problem IMO is much easier to solve with a single queue (unless you want something else).

Comment: I want to call also the `print` :) Anyway you would have to guarantee, that the producer start first - and it depends on the system

Comment: What's wrong with @Stefan's solution (only it works for me with simple `threads.each(&:join)`)? You can use `SizedQueue` if you need more control.

Comment: @Tombart Ruby's [`Queue`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) already handles the synchronization for you using `Mutex` internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more robust solution with multiple consumers and producers and usage of [MonitorMixin](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/monitor/rdoc/MonitorMixin.html), `MonitorMixin` has a special `ConditionVariable` with `wait_while()` and `wait_until()` methods

```
require 'monitor'

queue = []
queue.extend(MonitorMixin)
cond = queue.new_cond
consumers, producers = [], []

for i in 0..5
  consumers << Thread.start(i) do |i|
      print "consumer start #{i}\n"
      while (producers.any?(&:alive?) || !queue.empty?)
        queue.synchronize do
        cond.wait_while { queue.empty? }
        print "consumer #{i}: #{queue.shift}\n"
      end
      sleep(0.2) #simulate expense
    end
  end
end

for i in 0..3
  producers << Thread.start(i) do |i|
    id = (65+i).chr
    for j in 0..10 do
      queue.synchronize do
        item = "#{j} #{id}"
        queue << item
        print "producer #{id}: produced #{item}\n"
        j += 1
        cond.broadcast
      end
      sleep(0.1) #simulate expense
    end
  end
end

sleep 0.1 while producers.any?(&:alive?)
sleep 0.1 while consumers.any?(&:alive?)

print "queue size #{queue.size}\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, as you commented earlier, this approach only works if you can guarantee that the consumer thread gets to grab the mutex first at the start of our program. When this is not the case, a deadlock will occur as the first `resource.signal` of your producer thread will be sent at a time that the consumer thread is not yet waiting for the resource. As a result this first `resource.signal` will essentially not do anything, so you end up with a scenario where you call `resource.signal` 4 times (as the first one gets lost), whereas `resource.wait` is called 5 times. This means the consumer will be stuck waiting forever, and a deadlock occurs.

Luckily we can solve this by only allowing the consumer thread to start waiting if no more immediate work is available.

```
require 'thread'
queue = []
mutex = Mutex.new
resource = ConditionVariable.new
threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do
      if queue.empty?
        resource.wait(mutex)
      end
      value = queue.pop
      print "consumed #{value}\n"
    end
  end
end

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do
      queue << i
      print "#{i} produced\n"
      resource.signal
    end
    sleep(1) #simulate expense
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a [forum thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/552008) I came up with a working solution. It enforces alternation between threads, which is not ideal. What is we want multiple threads of consumers and producers?

```
queue = []
mutex = Mutex.new
threads = []

next_run = :producer

cond_consumer = ConditionVariable.new
cond_producer = ConditionVariable.new

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do
      until next_run == :consumer
        cond_consumer.wait(mutex)
      end

      value = queue.pop
      print "consumed #{value}\n"
      next_run = :producer
      cond_producer.signal
    end
  end
end

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    mutex.synchronize do
      until next_run == :producer
          cond_producer.wait(mutex)
      end
      queue << i
      print "#{i} produced\n"
      next_run = :consumer
      cond_consumer.signal
    end
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your problem:

```
require 'thread'
queue = Queue.new
consumer = Thread.new { queue.pop }
consumer.join
```

Because your main thread is waiting for the consumer thread to exit, but the consumer thread is sleeping (due to `queue.pop`) this results in:

```
producer-consumer.rb:4:in `join': deadlock detected (fatal)
    from producer-consumer.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

So you have to wait for the threads to finish without calling `join`:

```
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new
threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    value = queue.pop
    puts "consumed #{value}"
  end
end

threads << Thread.new do
  5.times do |i|
    queue << i
    puts "#{i} produced"
    sleep(1) # simulate expense
  end
end

# wait for the threads to finish
sleep(1) while threads.any?(&:alive?)
```

Comment: `queue.pop` is a blocking call, you're right. But I can remove `Queue.new` and replace it by normal `Array` and the problem stays the same

Comment: Still the thread is apparently sleeping forever so you cannot call `join`. You could circumvent the built-in deadlock detection with something like `sleep(1) while threads.any?(&:alive?)`.

Comment: @VictorMoroz It will raise `deadlock detected` if one of the threads was stopped, e.g. `Thread.new { Thread.stop }.join`

Comment: It doesn't in my case, unless you mean killed by exception. `sleep` in a thread doesn't result in a deadlock, at least not for my Ruby (1.8.7)

Comment: For MRI 1.9.3 both, [`Thread.stop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-stop) and [`Mutex#sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html#method-i-sleep) result in such deadlock.

Comment: That's [`Kernel#sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) and it's working without deadlock. [`Queue#pop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-pop) and [`ConditionVariable#wait`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/ConditionVariable.html#method-i-wait) however call [`Mutex#sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Mutex.html#method-i-sleep).

Comment: yeah, it's correct. thanks. I just wanted to do the synchronization manually with mechanism like semaphores or barrier

Comment: The problem with the code is, that you can get first `consumed 0` and then `0 produced` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Queue access and output are not synchronized. Thread 2 executes `queue << i`, thread 1 executes `value = queue.pop; puts "consumed #{value}"`, thread 2 executes `puts "#{i} produced"`.

Comment: The question was "How to use condition variables?"

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million the OP had an error (_deadlock detected (fatal)_) and assumed it was because of `ConditionVariable`, hence the title. I'm explaining in my answer that this conclusion is wrong. The error was caused by sending `join` to a sleeping thread, not because of using `ConditionVariable`.